# Ubuntu 16.04 desktop is blurry

Tags: 16.04, desktop-environments, gpu-driver

Just installed Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 on a HP Pro 400 G2 . Everything went good, I think I properly installed the video card driver which is an integrated intel hd graphic card driver. I rebooted, I had no errors but still the graphics are blurry or pixelated. Any thoughts on this?